# How to get a date after adding days :TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: Series

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get a new date after adding some days in the actual date. But I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: Series
```

My sample data and code is provided below:

```
data={'Date':['8/24/2020','8/26/2020','9/20/2020','10/26/2020','5/26/2020','4/26/2020'],
     'Days':[23,34,56,78,65,54]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Date','Days'])
df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.newdate=df.Date+timedelta(df.Days)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html#to-timedelta)

```
import pandas as pd

df['new_date'] = df.Date + pd.to_timedelta(df.Days, unit='d')
```

---

```
0   2020-09-16
1   2020-09-29
2   2020-11-15
3   2021-01-12
4   2020-07-30
5   2020-06-19
Name: new_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
def get_newdate(row):
 return row['Date'] + pd.Timedelta(days = row['Days'])
```

call the above function in the following manner

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df['newDate'] = df.apply(get_newdate, axis = 1)
```